# How do you search for an item in a LinkedLIst?

Tags: java, linked-list

For adding an item I use

```
public void add(Object s) {
    list.add(s);
}
```

For deleting an item I use

```
public void remove(Object s) {
    list.remove(s);
}
```

Now for searching the `LinkedList` when I use the dot operator and search the built in API I do not see anything that would suggest a search function. Would it be `contains`?

Comment: I recommend that you bookmark this URL - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html - the root of the Javadoc tree for the Java 7 SE APIs.  It holds the answers to your question and millions like it.

Comment: You were answered that you should use the `contains` method but you weren't happy with the answer "because it only returns true or false". So please describe your scenario a bit more in detail and maybe we can find you a better solution.

Comment: Agreed - I for one don't understand why you would need to get an object back when you're providing the object to search for. Please explain your use case in more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it seems you want to know *where* the item is placed in the list so you can access the actual instance found, you want to use [`indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) to find it and [`get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29) to return the found instance. There is no method that combines the two.

```
List list = ...
Object item = ...
int index = list.indexOf(item);
if (index > 0) {
    Object found = list.get(index);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes [contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method in LinkedList API will return `true` if it contains the search element.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for searching you would use the `contains` method. Note, however, that searching through a LinkedList takes an O(n) time, i.e. the time depends linearly on the size of the list, so if your list is big and you do lots of searches, you will want to use some other data structure. For example, you should probably initialize your list like this:

```
Collection something = new LinkedList();
```

Then, if you figure out that the performance of the search operations is hurting your program, you would just do this instead:

```
Collection something = new LinkedHashSet();
```

For a fancier search you should use a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) instead of a list or any other collection, but that's an entirely different data structure.

Comment: Well it will be under 200 objects, so that will not be a problem, the average would be under 50.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's [`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29). If you want something fancier, you'll have to write your own implementation of a `LinkedList` or come up with some utility functions.

Comment: Okay, that is what I was thinking as well, guess i can't get away with using the API alone.

Answer (score 0):

[`contains(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) is indeed what you're looking for. You could also use [`Collections.binarysearch(List, T)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T%29) if the list is sorted in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

Following code sample would make u understand

```
    // Assuming that we java imported java.util.LinkedList........

    LinkedList ll =new LinkedList();
    ll.add("red");
    ll.add("blue");
    ll.get(0);  // gets the first element.........
    ll.getFirst(); // returns the first element..
    ll.getLast(); // returns the last element....
    int position = ll.indexOf("red");        

    boolean status;
    status= ll.contains("red"); // returns true if list contains red or returns false....
```